# Some domains defaulting to first hosting package on WHM

Tags: web-hosting, apache, cpanel, linux, whm

Ok so I have a linux hybrid server running WHM/cPanel. I have the slight problem that when someone points their domain at our server, if there is no hosting package set up yet it defaults to the first hosting package it finds. Which is a site that begins with "a".

For example, a customer just bought a new domain name, we hadn't parked it on the hosting yet but they pointed it at our server. So it started loading a site that wasn't theirs that is the first hosting package alphabetically on the server that starts with "a".

I am not sure if this is specifically something Apache related, WHM related or what. Any pointers?

Comment: *...if there is no hosting package set up yet it defaults to the first hosting package...* Yes. That is exactly what web servers do with a request they do not recognize, they display the first site created.

Comment: Maybe you can create a hosting package aaaaaaaaaaaaa.com and put a holding page.  But I am not sure if it has to be a resolvable domain that it displays or just something that is set up on the server...closetnoc?

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes I get that it displays the first site created and why. Was looking for more of a solution to stop it doing that or going to a holding page as @Steve mentioned.

Comment: I'll add that as an answer, if it works you can accept

Answer (score 1):

If it displays the first hosting package on your server, maybe you can create a hosting package for a fictitious domain aaaaaaaaaaaaa.com and create what you wand as a holding page in the web space.

But I am not sure if it has to be a resolvable domain that it displays or just something that is set up on the server.  Let us know, we'll learn something too.